# DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE returned value equals HIGH value

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Why does this return values between 1 and 5?

```
declare
    v numeric;
begin
    v := dbms_random.value(1, 5);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v);
end;
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_random.htm#TTPLP71246) it should return values between 1 and 4.

Note: I am using Oracle 12c Release 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that the `numeric` data type can (optionally) take scale and precision. Importantly, if you don't specify them, the documentation says this:

> The NUMERIC and DECIMAL datatypes can specify only fixed-point
>   numbers. For those datatypes, the scale (s) defaults to 0.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213

You defined your data type as `numeric`, which Oracle translates to `number(38,0)` - meaning integer of at most 38 digits (the Oracle limit).

You generate fractional numbers with `RANDOM`, but when they are inserted in an integer column (as yours is, by applying the documented defaults) the values are rounded to the closest integer first. So this means that all the values you generate that are between 4.5 and 5.0 get rounded up to the integer 5.

To fix this, don't add scale and precision to `numeric`. Instead, get in the habit of using standard Oracle data types - `number` would be just fine in your case.

Answer (score 3):

It rounds the value for you.

```
declare
    v numeric(6,5);
    w numeric;
begin
    v := dbms_random.value(1, 5);
    w := v;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(w);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FLOOR(v));
end;
/
```

One result:

```
dbms_output:
4.92843
5
4
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're using `numeric` which is not a standard Oracle datatype. Looks like Oracle treats it as a synonym for `integer` and rounding to the nearest integer.

Try it with NUMBER and you probably won't see 5.000000000000 at all.